# Regexp that ignores everything after a question mark symbol

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

This is the full string I'm trying to parse with regular expressions:

```
example.com/newsite.com.html?var=/newsite.com&var=newsite.com
```

I would like to be able to match `newsite.com` part of the string but only if it does not appear after the `?` symbol.

Currently, I've only gotten so far:

```
/newsite.com/g
```

Which selects all the instances of `newsite.com` instead of just the first one.

Link to the regexp playground http://regexr.com/3fmre

**EDIT:**

Here `*` represents everything I would like to ignore, essentially matching only the first occurrence of `newsite.com` :

```
example.com/newsite.com.html?****************************
```

Comment: `[^?]*` will match everything except `?`

Comment: Thanks, but how would I use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with, it's not bullet-proof but works for the most part:

```
(?<=[^=]\/)newsite\.com
```

It ignores anything that starts with `=` and doesn't have a `/` in the beginning.

Note that this only works with regex implementations that support "positive lookbehind".

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `RewriteCond` and test the `REQUEST_URI` only. `QUERY_STRING` is not part of `REQUEST_URI` so, something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} newsite\.com
RewriteRule your rules if the cond if matched
```

Comment: This is actually what I'm trying to do now, but I'm stuck because I want to have a generic name like so: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %{SERVER_NAME}` but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. Are variables not allowed in the second part of the condition?

Comment: And also, if they do work, how would I escape the dot in the middle of the variable value? P.S. the `REQUEST_URI` **does** contain the `QUERY_STRING` But It doesn't matter since I could always test for the `!newsite\.com` in the query string separately.

Comment: It shouldn't contain it according to Apache's manual: "REQUEST_URI
The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING." http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: And no, the variables are only available to test things against, allow I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, odd, when I echo `REQUEST_URI` in php it shows the query string but if I test it directly it doesn't show it. Maybe php is using some other env variables. I'm trying to allow resources based on weather or not they contain the domain name within them.

Comment: Yeah, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` are not the same, even tho they both refer to Apache variables.

Comment: You could try `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .* RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %1` as `%1` refers to the last matched cond, but not sure you can use it in another cond. Not escaping it is not too much of an issue, you could have anything instead of the dot matching, but it's unlikely to happen. If it gets too complex, I'd consider testing this in PHP instead of using rewrite rules.

Comment: Good try, doesn't seem to work though. It seems like you can put only regular expressions inside the second part of the condition and no variables. I might need to rethink my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[^?]` which is an exclusion group, it matches every symbol except the ones specified in it, in this case a `?`. The expression `/^[^?]*/` for instance will match everything from the start until it finds a `?` (which wont be part of match).

If you want it to match only beginning from `newsite.com` you can use `/newsite\.com[^?]*/`, or from `?` to the end you can use `/[^?]*$/`.

Since you tagged `mod-rewrite` you also have the option to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` as condition. Query String is basically how we call what's after the `?` in the full URL.

Using `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} newsite.com` for instance will imply that the `RewriteRule` following this condition only applies if `newsite.com` is found on the Query String.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to ignore everything after `?` even the occurrence of `newsite.com`

Comment: @Danchm01 Perhaps you should tell us exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `%{QUERY_STRING}` this might actually be useful. As to the regular expression, your example matches `newsite.com` and then doesn't match `newsite.com?` but what I'm trying to do is ignore everything after `?` like so `newsite.com.html?**************` where the `*` is what is ignored

Comment: If you click on the playground link I gave it will be much easier to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of playing around with regexp but just using the other functions `mod-rewrite` offer you.

Comment: True, I'll try that too, although out of curiosity I'd still like to know if it's possible

Answer (score -1):

Here are two ways of doing it..

```js
        var str = "example.com/newsite.com.html?var=/newsite.com&var=newsite.com"; 
 //1. Look for ? and get the substring from 0 to the foundAt value
        var foundAt = str.indexOf('?');
            document.getElementById("substr").innerHTML = str.substr(0,foundAt);
            
//2. Using regex find the location of occurence of newsite.com and ignore rest          
 var str = "example.com/newsite.com.html?var=/newsite.com&var=newsite.com"; 
    var loc = str.search(/newsite\.com[^?]*/);
    document.getElementById("substr").innerHTML = loc;
```

```html
    <p id="substr"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this would be one solution but I'm only able to use regular expressions not a full programming language. So I wouldn't be able to use JavaScript and truncate the string with an array index.

Comment: post is tagged apache/mod-rewrite so there's no JS involved or available at this point